Why does the tension change instead of the speed of this object undergoing circular motion?
I recently came across the following problem:

A charged particle is whirled in a horizontal circle on a frictionless table, by attaching it to a string fixed at one end. If a magnetic field is switched on in the vertical direction then what happens to the tension in the string?

Here's what I thought:
There are two forces contributing to the centripetal force: the tension and magnetic force.
Tension acts radially inwards and magnetic force acts radially inwards or outwards depending on the charge of the particle and direction of the field.
So, $$T + F(\text{magnetic force}) =\frac{mv^2}r$$
Now, here $F$ is something which we have changed, and according to the answer key $v$ is constant, therefore tension changes. Can someone please let me know why that's the case. Couldn't $T$ be the constant and $v$ alter itself accordingly.

Don't you need to know the sign of the charge and the direction of the magnetic field (e.g., up or down) in order to answer this question?

@DavidWhite There will be only two cases (magnetic force pointing radially inwards or outwards). The question expects answers for these 2 cases. They say that the tension decreases if magnetic force points inwards and the vice versa.

For the speed to change, there must be a force acting in the direction of motion. But both the magnetic force and the tension force always act perpendicular to motion. There is no force that can accelerate the particle in the direction of motion, so its speed won't change.

This seems incorrect, you can have a central force that makes the particle move in or out,  and the velocity varies so that angular momentum is conserved. Just pull the string radially in.

Since the magnetic force is always perpendicular to the direction of motion of the particle, the force can only induce a centripetal acceleration. Or in simpler terms, the force can only change the direction of motion of the object and not its velocity. The same goes for the tension force provided by the string.
Now since both the forces can't change the velocity of the particle, the work done by the magnetic force and the tension force is $0$.
Since energy is conserved, $\frac{1}{2}mv_i^2 + 0=\frac{1}{2}mv_f^2 \implies v_i=v_f$.
Hence the velocity is constant. Now the only thing that can change to account for the magnetic force is the tension force, so it changes.

Is energy conserved for the particle? That magnetic field is definitely non-constant and could be of any strength.

@user121330 What makes you think that Energy is not conserved if the magnetic field is non-uniform? I'm pretty sure that from the question, I can assume that there arent any other dissipative factors like air resistance, friction force, eddy currents. etc

$ \nabla \times \mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t} $. Electric fields do work.
